# Can there be a machine where time zone is not set?

Tags: java, linux, timezone

I assumed that all systems(Windows, Mac, Linux, Solaris, SunOS, HP-UX, AIX, FreeBSD, NetWare, OS/400 et al) will have a time zone value. Hence I wrote the following program to get the local time zone of the system:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
public class LocalTimeZone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String local_time_zone;
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
        local_time_zone=df.getTimeZone().getID();
        System.out.println("local time zone: " + local_time_zone);
    }
}
```

**output:**
`local time zone: Asia/Calcutta`

time zone value is set in my machine and hence the output shows my local time zone.

Can there be a machine where time zone is NOT set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible, and is common on embedded Linux systems.  For example, when the whole OS has to run from flash memory in 64MB, the vendor might choose to not include time zones when they compile the Linux stack for their device.

Even when not set though, I would think that Java would return a default value (probably UTC), since it operates at a higher level.

AFAIK, there will always be a time zone set on Windows.  (I'm uncertain about WindowsCE)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes. Realistically, no. I think the most important question is what *should* you be supporting.  If you don't need to support fringe systems, then don't worry about it.

Comment: I heard from one of my friends that time zone NOT set is possible in linux. I searched about this in google and didn't get any relevant info. Hence I posted this question here. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Murali - Well, most Linux OSs want to keep timezone data on their software clock. Technically, there could be a system where there is no Time Zone but it really isn't something I would worry about. Systems like that tend to have very specific uses.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** There can, but shouldn't

Personally, I prefer dealing with UTC on my servers, as the concept of timezones and DST will screw things up when i move a machine around the world (in my line of work, that happens a lot). And even I have a timezone set: Reykjavik. It's the simplest way of getting a machine to run UTC without DST.

Comment: "*There can, but shouldn't*" > Can you be more specific? That's a very vague answer. Your second paragraph, while interesting, doesn't address the question so your "Short answer" is in fact your entire answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Even supposing you can find an operating system where the timezone isn't set, you won't be able to determine this from your Java code.

The timezone is retrieved from a `Calendar` object stored within the formatter. A `Calendar` is always associated with a timezone, using the value returned by `TimeZone.getDefault()` if you don't specify anything in the call to `Calendar.getInstance()`.

`TimeZone.getDefault()` will *always* return a time zone value, using `GMT` if it really cannot figure out what is being used locally. From [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--):

> - [Uses] `GMT` as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown